# Conditional sum in R in different columns

Tags: r, macos

I want to sum numbers in B column based on numbers in A column.
For example:

Column A : 2001 2002 2002 2002 2003 2003

Column B:  1     2    3    4    5    6

I want to add a column C that sums up B based on A. My desired result is:

Column A : 2001 2002       2002 2002 2003 2003

Column B:  1     2           3    4    5    6

Column C:  1     9 (2+3+4)   9    9    11   11

I have done a lot of search but really have no clue where to begin, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate` from `dplyr` after grouping by 'A'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    mutate(C= sum(B))
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$C <- with(df1, ave(B, A, FUN = sum))
```

---

An efficient option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, C := sum(B), by = A]
```

Comment: May I ask you one more question? What if there are two criteria, I need to add column C first based on A, then based on D,  I tried library(dplyr)
df1 %>%   group_by(A) , group_by(D)%>%  mutate(C= sum(B)), and I put the group_by(D) to many places, but did not work out.

Comment: @Amy  Two criteria, means two columns?  If that is the case `df1 %>% group_by(A, someothercolumn) %>% mutate(C = sum(B))`